# Does set mutating methods keep current elements?

Tags: python, set

Consider the following class:

```
class MyObj:
  def __init__(self, key, value):
     self.key = key
     self.value = value
  def __key(self):
    return self.key
  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.__key())
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return type(self) is type(other) and self.__key() == other.__key()


set1 = {MyObj(1,'a'), MyObj(3,'a'), ...}
set2 = {MyObj(1,'b'), MyObj(2,'b'), ...}
```

Is it guaranteed that after `set1 &= set2`, `set1` is `{MyObj(1,'a'), ...}` and not `MyObj(1,'b'), ...`.

Does the same apply for other mutating  methods like `union_update`, `difference_update`?

Update:
If you need to preserve the left elements, use the below:

```
set1 -= (set1-set2)
```

Comment: what? ... sets are unordered ... and immutable ... as such I am totally confused by your question

Comment: @JoranBeasley er.. sets are mutable, `frozenset`s are immutable.

Comment: ahh whoops .. sorry im going crazy you are totally right about their mutability ... but I stand my my earlier claim of "what?" ... also `&=` is intersection so I would expect `set1 &= set2` to result in `set1={}` since there is no intersection ...

Comment: oh, we 100% agree on `what`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) does not mention whether the binary operations somehow prefer the left or right argument, and thus I'd said that the result of that expression is implementation-defined. On CPython the *second* argument is preferred for intersection, while the first argument is preferred by union, as you can easily test:

```
In [1]: class MyObj:
   ...:   def __init__(self, key, value):
   ...:      self.key = key
   ...:      self.value = value
   ...:   def __key(self):
   ...:     return self.key
   ...:   def __hash__(self):
   ...:     return hash(self.__key())
   ...:   def __eq__(self, other):
   ...:     return type(self) is type(other) and self.__key() == other.__key()

In [2]: a = {MyObj(1, 'a')}

In [3]: b = {MyObj(1, 'b')}

In [4]: a & b
Out[4]: set([<__main__.MyObj at 0x7f4b5c17c650>])

In [5]: (a & b).pop().value
Out[5]: 'b'

In [6]: (b & a).pop().value
Out[6]: 'a'
```

(This example also show that the other answer is wrong since there *is* an intersection).

From the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/62cf4e77f785/Objects/setobject.c#l1315) of sets in CPython it's clear that when a common element is found only the element of the right operand is added to the result. This might not be the case in other implementations or versions.

---

I've just opened an [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue20902) in python bug tracker to see whether this information can be included in the documentation.